# Cast 'int' to `Random'

Tags: c#, random, casting

I have a function `foo(Random r)`  which has a Random in its input.

Sometimes the random is given by the user which then is not of type Random and I don't know how to assign a value of other types like `int` or `byte[]` to `Random`. 
I mean sometimes i need this function to be called like `foo(int r)`. 
By the way I just call this function from a dll and don't have the source.

how can i pass the `int` as `Random` ?

Comment: Create a new class of type Random and initialize it properly according to the library manual.

Comment: Does `foo()` extract a single random number from `r`? If so, you may have to refactor `foo` so that you have a function `foo(Int r)` which receives an integer, and `foo(Random r)` which receives a random number generator. Then the second method would call the first method with an integer.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I just mean a manual random given by user

Comment: please make sure to understand the difference between a __random value__ and a __random generator__!!  What you ask for literally is possible, but also totally crazy and useless.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?
This return just integer number which you set.

```
class NotRandom : Random
{
    public int Integer{get;set;}

    public NotRandom(int integer)
    {
        Integer = integer;
    }

    public override int Next()
    {
        return Integer;
    }

    public override int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        return Integer;
    }

    public override void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            buffer[i] = (byte)Integer;
    }

    protected override double Sample()
    {
        return (double)Integer;
    }

    public override int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        return Integer;
    }

    public override double NextDouble()
    {
        return (double)Integer;
    }
}
```

At Sample function
like

```
private int GetRandomNumber(Random rand)
{
   return rand.Next();
}
```

then, if you call as follow

```
int randNum = GetRandomNumber(new NotRandom(3));
```

randNum always have 3 that you pass the constructor of NotRandom as parameter.